# Как здесь получить макс. число и вводить так: max_value in files_{номер файла}?

Tags: python

```
import random

n = int(input("Quantity of files: ")) #n = 5
m = int(input("Quantity of numbers in each file: ")) # m = 10

lis = []
for i in range(0, m + 1):
    x1 = random.randint(0, m)
    lis.append(x1)


for i in range(1, n + 1):
    f = open(f'files_{i}.txt', 'w')
    f.write('{}'.format(lis))
    f.close()
    file_object = open(f'files_{i}.txt')
    num_list = map(int, file_object.read())

max_value = max(num_list)
print(max_value)
```

Comment: Во-первых, ничего не понятно, во-вторых, всё равно код неправильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

n = int(input("Quantity of files: ")) #n = 5
m = int(input("Quantity of numbers in each file: ")) # m = 10

def funcLis():
    lis = []
    for i in range(0, m + 1):
        x1 = random.randint(0, m)
        lis.append(x1)
    return lis

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    lis = funcLis()
    f = open(f'files_{i}.txt', 'w')
    f.write('{}'.format('{},'*len(lis)).format(*lis, *lis))
    f.close()
    file_object = open(f'files_{i}.txt')

    # num_list = map(int, file_object.read().split(','))           # -
    num_list = list(map(int, file_object.read().split(',')[:-1]))  # +

    # + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    print( f'files_{i}.txt: max={max(num_list)}')
```

---

```
files_1.txt: max=10
files_2.txt: max=8
files_3.txt: max=9
files_4.txt: max=9
files_5.txt: max=10
```

Comment: f.write('{}'.format('{},'*len(lis)).format(*lis, *lis)) что значит * в этом строке кода?

Comment: @Miracle распаковка списка, попробуйте: `lis = [1, 2, 3]; print(lis); print(*lis)`